# Handling multiple post-defined datasource connections based on user

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

How should I handle multiple user-connection defined datasource connection in my .NET application? To illustrate this better; the user provides three (3) pieces of information, username, password and data source name. This data source name is then looked-up in a central database telling that application which main database this user should connect to.

My question is, in the DataAccess layer, should we only pass down enough information to uniquely identify that user, and query the central database each time in the DAL; or, should we provide another way to pass the datasource connection down to the DAL?

[EDIT] This is a web application. [/EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

I would create a MyUser class that has information about which datasource they want to connect to. Upon authentication you can set this datasource as a property on your user class. The DAL can then query some kind of CurrentUser context and get the DS from there.